# WKInterfaceTable not selectable

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, wkinterfacetable, watchos-3

I am creating an app for `watchOS 3` using Xode 8 beta 6.
When creating a `WKInterfaceTable` with custom rows, I can't seem to get the selection working.

I do **not** want to perform a segue, I simply want to get `didSelectRowAtrowIndex`
called.

Setup:

- My row has an identifier
- The "Selectable" checkmark is set
- The custom class for my row is set
- WKInterfaceTable has an IBOutlet
- didSelectRowAt is implemented but is never called

The following function is not called:

```
override func table(_ table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int)
{print("selected \(rowIndex)")}
```

My row does not have a segue set, which seems to be a problem others had.
The table is part of a view that I open using a push segue

**rootViewController -push-> myViewWithTableController -touchCell-> nothing happens**

What am I missing?

Comment: I know you does not have segue set. but have you connected an action method to the table in your storyboard file ?

Answer (score 0):

I searched the document for any constraints for transition, but I couldn't find it.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/storyboard_elements/building_watchos_app_interfaces_using_the_storyboard/navigating_between_scenes

Tried with some patterns.

- rootController -nextPage -> tableController -push (touchCell) -> NG
- rootController -push -> tableController -push (touchCell) -> OK
- rootController -modal -> tableController -push (touchCell) -> NG
- rootTableController -push (touchCell) -> OK

If you change `Action Segue` of tableController from `Push` to `Modal`, you can transition.

Also, `didSelectRowAt` is not called when joining with segue in Storyboard.